# VS Code Extension for Images

Tags: image, vscode-extensions

I want to create a vscode extension that allows me to hover over an image (upload or from jupyter notebook numpy variable) and get the image's pixel coordinates and pixel value.

I wasn't able to find any tutorials and I wanted to ask much more experienced vs code extension developers for some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to get started:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples